# DbContext and Connection string (The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string)

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, dbcontext

Is there a way to pass a connection string to the DbContext constructor.
I really hate the idea of having a configuration setting in the app or web.config

When you want to reference your dll containing your EF model, you have to be aware of copying that stupid configuration, instead of having it in a central location and having the constructor access that setting, no matter where the dll goes.

Is this possible or are we forced to live with this frustration? Not every EF model lives in a web application or an exe.

Thanks

**UPDATE**:
I thought this error was related to a missing connection string in a config file. I'm passing a SqlConnection object and it gives me the same error. Why is this error happening?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the DbContext [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679467%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) overload that takes a string which can be the connection string.

```
string connectionString = "metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=\"data source=localhost;initial catalog=Test;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework\"";
using (DbContext db = new DbContext(connectionString))
{
    var m = db.Set<Main>().Take(1).First();
    Console.WriteLine(m.Id);
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I'm doing but every time i don't target my localhost\SQLEXPRESS instance throws and error: `The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.`

Comment: Not sure why you get that error. I copied the connection string from the config file, created a `DbContext` with it and it worked.  Will edit answer to include the code for comparison.

Comment: Do you need to have metadata files specified in your connection string for this to work? I thought the POCO approach didn't need any of that Metadata. I'm passing a plain SQL Server connection string for an existing database that I'm not planning to modify its structure.

Comment: Another point here is I'm inheriting from DbContext and trying to Initialize some values accessing the provider of the DbSet<T> properties.

Comment: Through DataAnnotations in my POCO classes